# Why is the Jacobi symbol $(D/m) = (D/n)$ for certain $m,n,D$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$m \equiv n$ mod $D$, $m,n >0$ and odd, and $D \equiv 0,1$ mod $4$, then $(D/m) = (D/n)$

I'm am sure that one can show this using quadratic reciprocity and the supplements. Any ideas?

Comment: it's in David A. Cox, Primes of the Form $x^2 + n y^2.$ Page 17 for odd positive $D.$ Even and/or negative $D$ are problem 1.11 on page 22, however the problem just says to finish this case yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D\equiv 1\pmod 4$, then 
$$ \left(\frac Dn\right)=(-1)^{\frac{D-1}2\frac{n-1}2}\left(\frac nD\right)=\left(\frac nD\right),$$
so the claim follws from $\left(\frac nD\right)=\left(\frac mD\right)$ (because $n\equiv m\pmod D$).

If $D=2^kE$ with $E$ odd $>1$, $k\ge 2$, then 
$$\begin{align} \left(\frac Dn\right)&=\left(\frac 2n\right)^k(-1)^{\frac{E-1}2\frac{n-1}2}\left(\frac nE\right)\\&=\left(\frac 2n\right)^k\left((-1)^{\frac{n-1}2}\right)^{\frac{E-1}2}\left(\frac nE\right).\end{align}$$
We can replace $n$ with $m $ in all places in the last line: From $n\equiv m\pmod D$ we have $n\equiv m\pmod E$, hence $\left(\frac nE\right)=\left(\frac mE\right)$. From $4|D$ we have $n\equiv m\pmod 4$ and hence $\frac{n-1}{2}\equiv \frac{m-1}2\pmod 2$. If $k=2$, then $\left(\frac 2n\right)^k$ and $\left(\frac 2m\right)^k$ both equal $(\pm1)^2=1$; and if $k>3$ then $n\equiv m\pmod 8$ hence $\left(\frac 2n\right)=\left(\frac 2m\right)$. Alltogether shows $\left(\frac Dn\right)=\left(\frac Dm\right)$.
This also solves the case $D=2^k$, i.e. $E=1$.

Comment: Thank you once again. I asked this because i supposedly need the proposition to show the well-definedness of the homomorphism in this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438347/why-is-the-jacobi-symbol-in-this-setting-a-unique-homomorphism